# Laravel. Conflict when building routes

Tags: laravel, routes

There are two routes:

```
Route::get('/{article:slug}', [ArticleController::class, 'showArticlePage']);
```

and

```
Route::get('/{user:nickname}', [ProfileInfoController::class, 'getUserByNickname']);
```

Is there any way for each of the routes to perform its function?You can't change uri

For example:

1. domain.com/nickname => I have to get the user
   There is a search in the table "users"

2.domain.com/my-first-article => I have to get the article
There is a search in the table "articles"

Note that each routes has its own controller and action, but they have a similar uri

Comment: No. This is not possible. Even if it is possible (most probably through middleware OR a generic controller), it won't be efficient e.g. each request will go through `articles` first and then `users`.

Comment: How can you tell it is a nickname or an article? What if there is a nickame the same as an article title?  Only option is to have a single generic route that tries everything (and this is a bad idea): `Route::get('/{slug}', [LookupController::class, 'lookup']);` and then `public function lookup($slug) { $user = User::where('nickname', $slug)->first();  if ($user->count()) { // it's a nickname!} $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first(); if ($article->count()) { // it's an article! }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **need** something to distinguish them it'll be a lot more helpful. E.g use an `@` in front of usernames.

Another approach would be if you know for sure all slugs will have a hyphen, then you can chain `->where('slug', '...')`

See https://pineco.de/handy-regex-constraints-in-laravel-routes/

Otherwise, it'll go through the first defined route.